# anchor tag with download attribute downloads when attributes are set or changed, in addition to on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put a couple of buttons to download either a csv or png of data from user queries. I got it going ok with window.open, except that I couldn't add a filename extension that way. So I added an a element around each of the two buttons and a js function to update the href and download attributes to reflect source and filename when the user makes the new query. The function that updates the href and download attributes is in the button click listener that performs the user queries. When I click the csv or png buttons, it downloads as it should. Unfortunately, the download also occurs when the data button is clicked. Is there some way to update those anchor element attributes but not cause the download? Is accessing/setting attributes of the element somehow simulating a click when I update the source and filename of the element?

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<br>
<br>
<a download href='blank' id="getcsv" style="visibility:hidden;"><button type="button" id="csvButton">Export to CSV</button></a>

<a download href='blank' id="getimage" style="visibility:hidden;"><button type="button" id="imgButton">Export Chart Image</button></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function bindSubmitButton(){
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // do stuff here to xmlhttprequest some stuff, put in chart_div

        bindImageDownload(chart.getImageURI().replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream'), queryType, ".png");
        bindCsvDownload(newArr, queryType, ".csv");

        });

// put image source and filename into the right anchor element
function bindImageDownload(imageSrc, title, extension){
    var buttonVar = document.getElementById("imgButton");
    buttonVar.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    var imgbuttondownload = document.getElementById("getimage");
    imgbuttondownload.setAttribute("href", imageSrc);
    imgbuttondownload.setAttribute("download", title+extension);
    imgbuttondownload.style.visibility = "visible";
    return;
}
</script>
```

Comment: waht YOu want I am not understand

Comment: Instead of only downloading when I click the <a download=name href=source><button></a>, the files force download every time the user updates clicks the submit button to perform their query. I'm trying to get it to download only when the <a> is clicked.